# Как добавлять только уникальные товары Django,

Tags: python, django

Как при помощи `create()` можно реализовать добавление уникальных товаров(точнее уникальным должно быть лишь одно поле)

`view`:

```
def parts(request):
added = ''
error = ''
PartAllView = Part.objects.order_by('-id')

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PartForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        added = 'Добавлено'
    else:
        error = 'Ошибка формы'

form = PartForm()

data = {
    'added': added,
    'error': error,
    'form': form,
    'PartAllView': PartAllView,
}

return render(request, 'kross/parts.html', data)
```

`model`:

```
class Part(models.Model):
brand = models.CharField('Производитель', max_length=100)
number = models.CharField('Артикул', max_length=100)
name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100)
description = models.TextField('Комментарий', blank=True, max_length=5000)
analog = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, related_name='AnalogParts')
images = models.FileField('Главное изображение', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте unique в поле вашей модели. Например:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
```